# 1-factor in r-connected graph

Tags: graph-theory

I have this problem in graph theory:
Let G be an r-connected graph of even order having no $K_{1,r+1}$  as an induced subgraph, for some r ≥ 1. Prove that G has a 1-factor.

So there are two directions I've been thinking of:

1. Induction on the number of vertices. the base is when |V(G)| = 2 and then its just 2 vertices connected with one edge between them and it is a 1-factor. The problem is in the induction step - assume we have a r-connected graph on k+2 vertices. I'd like to take out 2 of the vertices and use the induction hypothesis but how do I know I didn't damage the r-connectivity? I thought maybe to prove that every graph of even order can't be 2-connected because it has no $K_{1,r+1}$ as an induced subgraph but I wasn't able to do that and I started doubting if its true..
2. Usage of Tutte - a graph has a perfect matching if and only if for every S $\subseteq$ V, o(G-S) $\leq$ |S|. so if |S| < r, the graph is still connected and o(G-S) = 0 < |S|. but if not, how can I know anything about o(G-S)?

I would really appreciate any kind of help, even just to know which of the ways are closer to the solution...if I'm anywhere near it anyway.
thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Use Tutte's theorem. Argue that for every $S \subseteq V$ for which $G-S$ is not connected,

1. Every component of $G-S$ (even or odd) has edges to at least $r$ vertices in $S$.
2. Every vertex of $S$ has edges to at most $r$ different components of $G-S$.

Conclude that $G-S$ has at most $|S|$ components.

The even order of $G$ is used only in the special case $S = \varnothing$.

Comment: why 1 is true? why can't it be that one component has edges to lets say 2 vertices in S and another component has edges to r-2 vertices in S?

Comment: No, because then the graph is not $r$-connected. (Think about which vertices you can delete to disconnect it in that case.)

Comment: Hey there :) I haven't succeded to induce the conclusion from the other 2 facts you have suggested. Can you please explain how it comes from that idea?

Comment: @RonAbramovich Count the number of pairs $(v, C)$ where $v$ is a vertex of $S$, $C$ is a component of $G-S$, and there is an edge between $v$ and $C$. From fact 1, if $G-S$ has $k$ components, there are at least $kr$ such pairs. From fact 2, there are at most $r|S|$ such pairs. Therefore $k \le |S|$.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!

Comment: @MishaLavrov each vertex of $S$ has edges to at most $r$ components, but couldn't there be more than one edge from it to the same component?

Comment: @Ed_  We're not counting the number of edges a vertex has to a component at any point. We're just asking "does this vertex of $S$ have any edges to this component of $G-S$?" The answer is yes at most $r|S|$ times, but if it's less, that's not a problem.

Comment: Thank you. Your proof actually holds for all connected components right? Not just odd. ($c(G-S) \leq |S|$, where $c(G)$ is the number of connected components of $G$).

Comment: @Ed_ Yes, though the even components aren't relevant for Berge-Tutte.